# Retrofi E/response-failure

Tags: android, retrofit

I am fairly new to the android development world and currently working on an app that uses Retrofit to send data to a certain server. The data that has been sent will be saved on the server but it does not return any response.

I have tried it using PostMan and it returns what is intended, but when ever try it from the app it doesn't seem to return anything.

A sample JSON data that i am trying to send

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "user_id": null,
            "user_first_name": "Thanos",
            "user_last_name": "",
            "user_phone": "+1000000000",
            "user_photo": "/images/doctorstrange.png",
            "user_city": "Titan",
            "user_email": "doctorstrange@titan.com",
            "user_pass": "iaminevitable",
            "user_status": "End Game",
            "user_phenotic_name": "The Mad Titan",
            "user_country": "Titan",
            "country_id": 1,
            "registration_date": null,
            "gender": "Male"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Response JSON I am expecting

```
{
    "status": 81,
    "msg": "The User information is saved."
}
```

The POJO Class for the Response

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("msg")
@Expose
private String msg;

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMsg() {
return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
this.msg = msg;
}

}
```

The POJO Class for Users

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("user_id")
private Object userId;

@SerializedName("user_first_name")
private String userFirstName;

@SerializedName("user_last_name")
private String userLastName;

@SerializedName("user_phone")
private String userPhone;

@SerializedName("user_photo")
private String userPhoto;

@SerializedName("user_city")
private String userCity;

@SerializedName("user_email")
private String userEmail;

@SerializedName("user_pass")
private String userPass;

@SerializedName("user_status")
private String userStatus;

@SerializedName("user_phenotic_name")
private String userPhenoticName;

@SerializedName("user_country")
private String userCountry;

@SerializedName("country_id")
private Integer countryId;

@SerializedName("registration_date")
private Object registrationDate;

@SerializedName("gender")
private String gender;


public User(Object userId, String userFirstName, String userLastName, String userPhone, String userPhoto, String userCity, String userEmail, String userPass, String userStatus, String userPhenoticName, String userCountry, Integer countryId, Object registrationDate, String gender) {

this.userId = userId;
this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
this.userLastName = userLastName;
this.userPhone = userPhone;
this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
this.userCity = userCity;
this.userEmail = userEmail;
this.userPass = userPass;
this.userStatus = userStatus;
this.userPhenoticName = userPhenoticName;
this.userCountry = userCountry;
this.countryId = countryId;
this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
this.gender = gender;
}

public Object getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Object userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserFirstName() {
return userFirstName;
}

public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
}

public String getUserLastName() {
return userLastName;
}

public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
this.userLastName = userLastName;
}

public String getUserPhone() {
return userPhone;
}

public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
this.userPhone = userPhone;
}

public String getUserPhoto() {
return userPhoto;
}

public void setUserPhoto(String userPhoto) {
this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
}

public String getUserCity() {
return userCity;
}

public void setUserCity(String userCity) {
this.userCity = userCity;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public String getUserPass() {
return userPass;
}

public void setUserPass(String userPass) {
this.userPass = userPass;
}

public String getUserStatus() {
return userStatus;
}

public void setUserStatus(String userStatus) {
this.userStatus = userStatus;
}

public String getUserPhenoticName() {
return userPhenoticName;
}

public void setUserPhenoticName(String userPhenoticName) {
this.userPhenoticName = userPhenoticName;
}

public String getUserCountry() {
return userCountry;
}

public void setUserCountry(String userCountry) {
this.userCountry = userCountry;
}

public Integer getCountryId() {
return countryId;
}

public void setCountryId(Integer countryId) {
this.countryId = countryId;
}

public Object getRegistrationDate() {
return registrationDate;
}

public void setRegistrationDate(Object registrationDate) {
this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
}

public String getGender() {
return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
this.gender = gender;
}

}
```

The Interface Class

```
    @Headers({

            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("addUser.json")
    Call<BaseResponse> addUser(@Body UserRequest userRequest);
```

The User Request Class

```
public class UserRequest {
    @SerializedName("users")
    public List<User> users;


}
```

and the code that runs on Signup Button clicked

```
signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


               //Retrofit - Insert Values that will be sent to the server
                UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
                ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
                User user = new User(
                        null, // for the id since its an auto-increment field in the server's database
                        "" + firstName.getText().toString(), 
                        "" + lastName.getText().toString(),
                        "" + mobileNumber.getText().toString(),
                        "" + "photo from storage",
                        "" + city.getText().toString(),
                        "" + emailAddress.getText().toString(),
                        "" + password.getText().toString(),
                        "End Game", // status is sent on default
                        "" + phoneticName.getText().toString(),
                        "" + userCountry.getText().toString(),
                        "" + "countryId", // id is default sent
                        "" + Constanst.GetCurrentDate(),
                        "" +  gender.getSelectedItem().toString());

                userList.add(user);
                userRequest.users = userList;

                // Using the Retrofit
                BaseRestInterface baseRestInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(BaseRestInterface.class, "" + GlobalVariables.BASE_URL + "users/");
                Call<BaseResponse> baseResponseCall = baseRestInterface.User(userRequest);
                baseResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse> call, Response<BaseResponse> response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID = " + response.body().getStatus()
                                + "\n"
                                + response.body().getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Log file

```
E/response-failure: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@d6f630d
    Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Using this i was able to send data to the server, the problem is i don't get any response from server, i just get response failure. Any one can help/ or see what i might have done wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit rely's on OkHttp so you can add the [`OkHttpLoggingInterceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) so you can see what the body of the response is coming back from your service.

Based on that log message you are probably dealing with an extra json field or a missing one and the `LoggingInterceptor` will expose that so you can fix it.